# I can not make PUT request in restful spring-boot aplication

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, postman

[postman PUT request screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9aR0.png)
I am creating a restful spring application, but I can not make PUT request work. Every time I try to make PUT request I get this error in Postman: "Required request body is missing" however, request body seems to be correct.

```
@RestController
class SimulatorsController {
    private final RacetrackRepository racetrackRepository;

    SimulatorsController(RacetrackRepository racetrackRepository) {
        this.racetrackRepository = racetrackRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/simulators")
    public Iterable<Racetrack> all(){

        return racetrackRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/simulators/{id}")
    public Racetrack one(@PathVariable Integer id) throws Exception {

        return racetrackRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new Exception());
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Racetrack addNewRacetrack(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "track") String name,
                           @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1000") double price,
                           @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1000") int exerciseDuration,
                           @RequestParam(defaultValue = "purple") String colour,
                           @RequestParam(defaultValue = "cross") String exercise) {
        Racetrack racetrack = new Racetrack(name, price, exerciseDuration, colour, exercise);
        return racetrackRepository.save(racetrack);
    }
```

GET, POST and DELETE methods works

```
    @PutMapping("/simulators/{id}")
    public Racetrack updateRacetrack(@RequestBody Racetrack newRacetrack,
                               @PathVariable Integer id){

        return  racetrackRepository.findById(id)
                .map(racetrack -> {
            racetrack.setName(newRacetrack.getName());
            racetrack.setPrice(newRacetrack.getPrice());
            racetrack.setExerciseDuration(newRacetrack.getExerciseDuration());
            racetrack.setColour(newRacetrack.getColour());
            racetrack.setExercise(newRacetrack.getExercise());
            racetrack.setId(id);
            return racetrackRepository.save(racetrack);
                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    newRacetrack.setId(id);
                    return racetrackRepository.save(newRacetrack);
                });
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/simulators/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteRacetrack(@PathVariable Integer id){

        racetrackRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "deleted";
    }
}
```

[image: postman screen]

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: @burm87: The problem may not be the code, but the way Postman is being used.

Comment: You are sending a regular form with postman NOT a request body using JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Cross check your POSTMAN request. Check for the content type as application/json. the image is just an example.....

[image]